# tx_news mailing by direct_mail in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-7.6.x

I create subscription form with "formhandler". Added authorization code by "authcode" and added direct_mail categories by DB finisher in "formhandler". Now my task to send users news from tt_news extension, filter by language and categories chosen in "formhandler" subscription form.
Somebody have ideas how add directly connect content from "tx_news" in direct_mail mailing. And filter them by language and categories. Of course it be nice to choose which news send and which not

I find some examples how to add content from tt_news in direct_mail https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/direct_mail/Configuration/ConfiguringPlainTextRenderingOfNewsRecords/Index.html. Maybe somebody now how to add from tx_news. Or maybe I need use a total different approach?